# Error: package com.google.android.exoplayer2 does not exist

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, oculus

Attempting to build a VR/Oculus project in Unity 20201.14 and the build keeps failing with this error. Any ideas on how I might fix this?

```
\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\oculus\videoplayer\NativeVideoPlayer.java:21: error: package com.google.android.exoplayer2 does not exist 
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by deleting and reinstalling the Oculus Integration package.